# find and collect values of all elements having `data-id` attribute

Tags: jquery

How to find all elements having `data-id` attribute and collect the values using `map` function.

```js
var target = $('#parent');
var arr = target.find('all elements having data-id attribute');
var cnt = $.map(arr, (e) => $(e).data('id')).join(',');
console.log(cnt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
<div class='title' data-id = 5>lorem</div>
<input type = 'text'>
<a href='google.com' data-id = 14>google</a>
<div class='title'>ipsum</div>
<img class='imgtop' src='' alt='img' data-id = 9>
</div>
```

Result should be `5,14,9`

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), like : `target.find('[data-id]');`

```js
let target = $('#parent'),
  arr = target.find('[data-id]'),
  cnt = $.map(arr, (e) => $(e).data('id')).join(',');
console.log(cnt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
  <div class='title' data-id="5">lorem</div>
  <input type='text'>
  <a href='google.com' data-id="14">google</a>
  <div class='title'>ipsum</div>
  <img class='imgtop' src='' alt='img' data-id="9">
</div>
```

Also see [attributeHas selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

This is as simple as

```
const arr = target.find('[data-id]')
```

See https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/